# Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version(>=3.0.0)

Tags: wpf, nuget, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I am trying to migrate my WPF(.net framework) project to WPF(.net core 3).
So i have installed [this Visual Studio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BrianLagunas.ConvertProjectToNETCore3) and i m now able to create a new Wpf(.net core) project , but the problem starts when i add a nuget package ! , VS throws me this error :

```
Unable to find package Microsoft.NETCore.App with version (>= 3.0.0-preview6-27730-01)
- Found 69 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 3.0.0-preview5-27626-15 ]
- Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages    TestwpfCore C:\Users\sintware\source\repos\TestwpfCore\TestwpfCore\TestwpfCore.csproj   1
```

Comment: The error comes when i install, **MahApps.Metro**, it supports only .NetFramework, but even when i install abp (that supports core 2)  the error is triggred

Comment: You can now install the latest .net core 3.0 preview6 version from [this link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)(which released 6.12). Then rebuild your solution to check if it helps. Actually, I've checked the extension you mentioned and use it to convert my wpf app, but it works well when adding that MahApps.Metro package.

Comment: Hi friend, just checking in if this issue won't block you:) If same issue persists, you can share a simple sample(After deleting the core code) so that we can check it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting @Lance is comment , i downloaded the [Core 3 preview 6](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0) and finally the problem is gone ,i can install nuget package without any problem.

Answer (score 4):

As dotnet core 3.0 is still in preview, you should put the following in a file called NuGet.Config in the root of your project (or merge with your existing file):

```
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="dotnet-core" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-core/index.json" />
    <add key="dotnet-windowsdesktop" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet-windowsdesktop/index.json" />
    <add key="aspnet-aspnetcore" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/aspnet-aspnetcore/index.json" />
    <add key="aspnet-aspnetcore-tooling" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/aspnet-aspnetcore-tooling/index.json" />
    <add key="aspnet-entityframeworkcore" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/aspnet-entityframeworkcore/index.json" />
    <add key="aspnet-extensions" value="https://dotnetfeed.blob.core.windows.net/aspnet-extensions/index.json" />
    <add key="gRPC repository" value="https://grpc.jfrog.io/grpc/api/nuget/v3/grpc-nuget-dev" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This will make sure the preview versions can be found!

This information can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk#installers-and-binaries

As soon as dotnet core 3.0 is released you should be able to remove these package sources.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the error message says it's trying to find a package with version 3.0.0 preview6. If you go to https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0 you can see the latest public preview is preview 5. Therefore you, or the tool you used to migrate, is trying to use a nightly build of the .NET Core SDK, not a published version. The .NET SDK normally ships with its packages which get put in the NuGet Fallback Folder, so it appears that version of the .NET Core SDK wasn't installed correctly.

I know nothing of that extension you linked, plus it's not a Microsoft extension, so while I appreciate the effort the developer made to create it, I don't know if it works "correctly". Plus .NET Core 3.0 still isn't generally available, so maybe the extension worked with previous previews but something changed.

My suggestion is to install the latest .NET Core 3.0 preview from the download page, go to an empty directory and run "dotnet new wpf", then copy all your code and xaml into that new directory. I don't trust migration tools, I prefer to do it myself manually, so I understand what's being changed.

Comment: I installed net core 3 from github before using the tool.
i took your advice , with a cmd i create the wpf project, but adding abp with nuget returns the same error.
so apparently as  i said core3 works with core3 nuget packages !

Comment: I don't know why your fallback folder doesn't contain the packages, or why your project isn't using the fallback folder, but you'll need to install the publicly released preview to have a version with packages on nuget.org. The install script on github installs a nightly build that does not have matching packages on nuget.org.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue, which ended up being caused by my global nuget.config file being empty. Although my solution nuget.config was correct it seems that the generated project builds without using the solution nuget.config, and instead uses the global one, which being empty, did not work.

The solution was to include the nuget.org package source in the package sources in the `%AppData%\NuGet\NuGet.config` file, so that it looked like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumping up the Agent Specification from windows-2017 to windows-2019 did it for me